# \pause does not work with shrink=20

Tags: beamer, overlays, pause, fit

I need to shrink the material on the slides (involves a lot of text/pics). I am using `shrink=20` on most frames. Once I use `shrink=20` on a frame, then `\pause` is not working properly, it just duplicates the whole slide.  It works properly if I remove the shrink. Other overlays commands also just duplicate the slides.

I have tried to define `\begin{frame}{pause}[shrink=20]` as well (changing the order too), but in this case, it ignores `shrink=20`.....

What am I doing wrong? Any advice on how to use shrink and pause simultaneously?

I am using Texpad (Version 1.8.9 (460)) on MacOS.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\usetheme{Boadilla}


\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\mode<presentation>
\title[Talk]{Talk}

\author[SMith]{Smith}
\institute[AAA]{AAA}
\date[4/19/2019]{Talk\\April 19, 2019}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\section[Introduction]{Introduction}


\begin{frame}[shrink=20]
\frametitle{Introduction} 
Some stuff \\\ %If I input \pause here it duplicates the whole slide

Other stuff\\\  



   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, If I remove `shrink=20` it works properly. Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! I do not see any unexpected behavior on my TeXLive 2018 distribution.

Comment: Thank you! I am using Texpad, I have also attached a screenshot. As you can see it just duplicates the slide....

Comment: Please add your log file so we can see which version of beamer you use.